# Timing problem by using fadeOut in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, fadeout

I having problem with my jQuery code.

in start it display text with shuffled effect, then after 11 sec it fade out and do this again. After a while I got fadeOut effect in beginning of shuffling effect.

It seems they run on different timeline.

```
$( document ).ready( function(){

     function textShuffle() {
        $( "#text" ).shuffleLetters().fadeIn().delay( 11000 ).fadeOut( 400 );
        setTimeout( textShuffle, 12000 );
     }
     textShuffle();

});
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: This is a circular function: it calls itself over and over again.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what the problem is from your description: "It seems they run on different timeline.".  I took the code as shown above, stripped out the `.shuffleLetters()` to just test the remaining jQuery, and it worked as I would have expected.  Can you please update to describe the (1) behavior you expect and (2) the actual behavior, and how it differs from what is expected.  It might not hurt to use a fiddle or inline example in your question that reproduces the issue (ideally stripping out superfluous code).  This will invite good answers.  Good luck!

Comment: @YaakovAinspan Yeah, I want it that way to repeat endlessly. My problem is after a while fadeOut runs on wrong time.
It must run 11 secs after shuffling but after a while it occure in begining of in middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @alexander-nied mentioned by removing .shuffleLetters() rest of script works fine, I realized that function takes more time than 600ms to complete and I can't determine how much time it need to complete the task.

So now I added promise() to #text before calling setTimeout()

```
function textShuffle() {
    $( "#text" ).shuffleLetters().fadeIn().delay( 11000 ).fadeOut( 400 );
    $( "#text" ).promise().done( function(){
            setTimeout( textShuffle, 1 );
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call the recursive method after fadeOut completes, like this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    function textShuffle() {
        $("#text").shuffleLetters().fadeIn().delay(11000).fadeOut(400, Function() {
            setTimeout(textShuffle, 12000);});
    }

    textShuffle();
});
```